# Adding elements to a specified index in python Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, append

How can I place a value inside an array witha  specified index. Like how can I place the `number` 3 inside between the 4th and the 5th element in `array`.

```
number = 3
index= 5
array= np.array([ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31])
```

Expected Output

```
[ 31, 28, 31, 30, 3, 31, 30, 31, 31]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.insert`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html)

```
import numpy as np

np.insert(array, index, number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `numpy.insert` function to insert a value at a specified point in a `numpy.array`. Here is how you would use it in your case:

```
array = np.array([ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31])
np.insert(array, 5, 3)
```

The second argument is the index before which you wish to insert the value, which is the third argument. See the [documentation here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) for more information, especially for higher-dimensional arrays, which can get a bit more complicated.